# Cannot copying file from Android to Linuxmint 17.3 Desktop "libmtp error: Could not get file from device"

Tags: android, linux-mint, mtp

I am trying to copy image file to backup it on my desktop which is linux mint (17.3 or Rosa) installed. I am using Infinix X510 phone with the newest version of android 6. At the beginning it was OK. But, at the end i get the message

> “libmtp error: Could not get file from device”

I tried the solution as found by Googling here https://askubuntu.com/questions/879029/libmtp-error-could-not-get-file-from-device-on-attempting-to-transfer-files

But, it wasn't working for me. Is there a way to solve this matter? I need file to support my company job which [supplying cosmetics](http://adevnatural.com/supplier-kosmetik-bpom-online-murah-harga-pabrik-grosir-agen-kosmetik/).

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing the file to a compressed format(tar,zip).Copy the file and then decompress it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the filename was the solution for me e.g: file.mkv to file.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename file, make sure file name not contain (-) (:) etc. Just rename it to alphabet